# Using Files.listFolder from dropbox 2.0 API to keep up with changes of files in folder

Tags: java, dropbox, delta

I'm trying to implement "keep up with changes to files and folders" on dropbox using DbxClientV2. I was able to construct the following:
        TreeMap children = new TreeMap();
        Files.ListFolderResult result;

```
    String cursor = null;

    while (true) {
        result = client.files.listFolder("/MyDirectory/Reports");
        if (!result.cursor.equals(cursor)) {
            cursor = result.cursor;
            for (Metadata md : result.entries) {
                if (md instanceof DeletedMetadata) {
                    children.remove(md.pathLower);
                } else {
                    children.put(md.pathLower, md);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!result.hasMore) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I retrive cursor of "/MyDirectory/Reports" folder from dropbox server to check whether I should update my local repository "children"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question you're asking, so I don't know if this answers it, but your code doesn't seem to actually use the cursor. I would think you want something more like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = client.files.listFolder("/MyDirectory/Reports");
    } else {
        result = client.files.listFolderContinue(cursor);
    }
    cursor = result.cursor;
    for (Metadata md : result.entries) {
        ...
```

If that doesn't help, can you please rephrase your question?